# Startup Repair with CD

Tags: windows, windows-xp, repair

Google doesn't seem to give any clear answers to this.

I have a broken `Windows XP` install which I need to repair. I have the CD. When I boot from the CD, I do not get an option to press R. I only get the screen where I can install or delete a partition (Press Enter, C, D).

It has been many years since I have done this. Is there repair screen on the partition select page or have I missed it?

Comment: It should be the first option you see: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ss/rconsole_3.htm

Is your enter key stuck down?

Comment: If memory serves, you may not see the "R"epair option is the Windows Setup didn't detect an existing version of Windows. But it's been a while now since I last ran an XP CD. :)

Comment: To expand on techie007's comment: I believe (but I might be 100% wrong here) that in order for the Repair option to appear, you must have the same level SP as what is installed on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

At the install or delete partition page, choose install on the C partition. It should then check to see if a previous copy of XP is on that partition. It will then present it and there should be an option to repair it.